# User can't add favorites in IE

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012, internet-explorer

I have an interesting issue where an end user using Windows 7 on my Server 2012 domain can't add websites to their Favorites in IE. They get the following error message:

[image: IE error message]

They get the same error if they click "Organize Favorites" as well. I couldn't find anything related online. How can I resolve this? I'm assuming it has something to do with the user's profile paths, etc. but I don't have any GPOs set up pertaining to that.

If it's relevant, I do not have any roaming profiles turned on.

Comment: What local permissions have you given the user, can you give them local admin and then see if the issue persists. Also try turning off UAC.

Comment: I made the user local admin, as well as tried downgrading, then reinstalling IE 11, both with no effect. I'll probably just try reinstalling Windows to see if that resolves the issue. No other user is encountering the problem.

Comment: I have a wicked problem that might be similar on my computer... I can't open Internet Options, neither from inside IE nor from Control Panel. Actually the simplest manifestation of the problem is going to a command prompt and typing `inetcpl.cpl`. It should open internet options, but on my computer just exits doing nothing. I have no solution for this, after trying 100 different things... : - (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by reinstalling Windows and rejoining. Turns out the image I used to install the first time - was corrupt (and didn't seem to be fixed with `sfc /scannow`).

There may be other solutions for this so I'll leave it open so others can be helped.

Comment: You should mark as answer whichever answer resulted in solving your problem, even if the answer is yours. The other answers will remain and future visitors with your question will have to decide which strategy works best for them.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming it's just the one workstation, yes?

Try resetting the default program for html (I know, you said IE is the default already).

Go to Control Panel -> Programs -> Default Programs -> Set your default programs.

[image]

Set IE as default and Choose defaults for this program (associate htm, html, etc.).

(Another link I found suggested editing the registry at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ for the various file extensions, but try using the actual control panels first.)

Answer (score 1):

I've spent a bunch of time trying to find a GPO that would prevent this... But I think it may be a simple permissions problem.

Check and make sure that

> %userprofile%\favorites
>
> (C:\users\\favorites

and

> %userprofile%\favororites\links

are writable by the users in question.